# SQL Rounding to 2 decimals in my specific query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i have found ways to round to 2 decimals normally, but i need to round the equation here to 2 decimals and everything i type seems to have an error, so im hoping someone can help out im sure its something simple. here is my query and the results, i need the sales tax and subtotal rounded to 2 decimal places

```
/*------------------------
SELECT OrderID,
       ItemID,
       ROUND(price, 2) AS [Price],
       '$' + CAST(ROUND(price * 0.06, 2) AS VARCHAR(7)) AS [Sales Tax],
       '$' + CAST(ROUND((price * .06) + price, 2) AS VARCHAR(8)) AS [Subtotal]
from ORDER_ITEM
where price >= 20
order by OrderID;
------------------------*/
OrderID     ItemID      Price                                   Sales Tax Subtotal
----------- ----------- --------------------------------------- --------- ---------
1004        1004        32.50                                   $1.9500   $34.4500
1016        1020        47.95                                   $2.8800   $50.8300
1018        1018        47.50                                   $2.8500   $50.3500
1019        1017        80.00                                   $4.8000   $84.8000
1020        1019        30.00                                   $1.8000   $31.8000
1021        1031        25.99                                   $1.5600   $27.5500
1031        1029        82.50                                   $4.9500   $87.4500
1032        1037        85.00                                   $5.1000   $90.1000
1033        1032        100.00                                  $6.0000   $106.0000
1035        1038        145.00                                  $8.7000   $153.7000
1036        1049        20.00                                   $1.2000   $21.2000
1038        1054        57.50                                   $3.4500   $60.9500
2001        2000        175.50                                  $10.5300  $186.0300
2002        2002        125.00                                  $7.5000   $132.5000
3021        2030        35.00                                   $2.1000   $37.1000
3022        2031        145.00                                  $8.7000   $153.7000

(16 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: round(column_name,2)

Comment: if it was just the column name it would be easier, i have the column cast as [sales tax] and if i type round(sales tax,2) or even if i change it to sales_tax, it gives me an error and says its an invalid column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is full version of your query which uses the `ROUND()` function.

```
SELECT OrderID,
       ItemID
       ROUND(price, 2) AS [Price],
       '$' + CAST(CAST(ROUND(price * 0.06, 2) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS VARCHAR(8)) AS [Sales Tax]
       '$' + CAST(CAST(ROUND((price * .06) + price, 2) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS VARCHAR(8)) AS [Subtotal]
```

**Update:**

My feeling now is that you would do *much* better if you changed your currency columns to the type `DECIMAL(18,2)` (or something else with 2 decimal places).  This would avoid messy and unnecessary casts and rounding.

Comment: use CONCAT('$' , ROUND((price * .06) + price, 2) AS [Subtotal]  -- to add strings

Comment: i get this error with that code --    Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.   and with the concat one it says Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: @Chris Please try it again.

Comment: tried again tim, i got this error  Msg 1035, Level 15, State 10, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'.                                                              and then i even took out line 5, which made the query work except it showed sales tax with still 4 decimal places

Comment: i have done what you said, and it still does not round down, look at my edited original post please, i appreciate the help, i dont understand why it does not go to 2 decimals still

Comment: Try casting to `DECIMAL(18,2)` and let us know if that works for you.  By the way, it _was_ giving you two digits of precision after the decimal point, but it was filling in extra zeroes, which I suspect you don't want.

Comment: you are correct in assuming i did not want the extra zeroes, i tried the new code and now it says this  -     Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.  i want it to show as if it were money, and i dont know anyone who uses hundreths of cents, lol this is pretty irritating

Comment: Here is my last attempt.  Give it a try.

Comment: The last attempt worked Perfectly! Thanks so much for your help tim!

Answer (score 0):

```
select OrderID, ItemID
    , cast (price as char (6)) as [Price]
    , '$' + cast ((round(price * .06), 2) as char (7)) as [Sales Tax]
    , '$' + cast ((round(price * .06 + price), 2) as char (8)) as [Subtotal]
from ORDER_ITEM
where price >= 20
order by OrderID;
```

Try this. You have to surround the numerical variables with `round`

Comment: i gave that a shot matt, this is what i got --  Msg 189, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
The round function requires 2 to 3 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TRUNCATE command.
Truncate always "rounds" down.
Refer following link for examples.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate